# Do we have predictive search capability within Sitecore?

Tags: content-search

I'm looking for predictive search for content page in Sitecore.

Something similar, what google search provide. Do we have anything like this?

Comment: Are you using anything outside of the standard Sitecore search API? e.g. Solr, Coveo, etc. Also, what version of Sitecore are you running?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "predictive" search? It will help greatly if you can give an example query by a user and an expected response by the website.

Answer (score 17):

So this depends on what you mean by predictive search.

If you mean a simple autocomplete, then yes. Sitecore provide an n-gram analyzer for both Lucene and Solr. To use this, add a new field to the index and map the field to use the `n-gram` analyzer instead of the default. You will need a custom computed field and an update to the `schema.xml` - see this post for more detail: http://www.ehabelgindy.com/sitecore-7-solr-search-auto-complete-using-ngram/

If you mean a full predictive and smart search "like" Google, then not out of the box with Sitecore. There are a few options to be able to do this tho.

**Coveo**

The most straightforward would be to use **[Coveo for Sitecore](http://www.coveo.com/en/solutions/coveo-for-sitecore/features)**. Coveo offers a few cool features that you can plug into Sitecore, predictive search/auto complete looks to be included in that.

**Custom Implementation**

You can roll your own implementation of this using either the Lucene or Solr indexes. I would suggest that you use Solr for this as it has some nice features in the API that you would have to implement yourself with Lucene.

Doing a custom implementation is pretty complex tho, you would need a custom index, custom crawler to make sure that the correct page content was included etc...

Although I'd like to put the whole answer here, its would be a bit long, so here are some links to instructions:

http://www.cominvent.com/2012/01/25/super-flexible-autocomplete-with-solr/

If you can be more specific with the requirements, we can tailor the answer to your needs.

Comment: I haven't explore coveo but thanks for the direction.in past I worked with episerver with eps fast search which help you define dictionary which comes with all lexicon smarts around grammer suggestions etc.i was looking for similar thing for sitecore.